# time frequency in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good Afternoon, colleagues!I have some problems with the following task: I need to plot the time-series graph  by using parameter "frequency" that defines the time between two observations in my graph. The data are shown below:

```
     date  time   open   high    low  close
1 1999.04.08 11:00 1.0803 1.0817 1.0797 1.0809
2 1999.04.08 12:00 1.0808 1.0821 1.0806 1.0807
3 1999.04.08 13:00 1.0809 1.0814 1.0801 1.0813
4 1999.04.08 14:00 1.0819 1.0845 1.0815 1.0844
5 1999.04.08 15:00 1.0839 1.0857 1.0832 1.0844
6 1999.04.08 16:00 1.0842 1.0852 1.0824 1.0834
```

By default in this data the frequency is 1 hour, but I have two questions: 
 - how to define this frequency in the data (by automatically, if the data will be other one) (because I tried to select column `time` and to calculate `frequency = time[2]-time[1]` but I got an error)
 
- if we task the required frequency is 3 hour how to select this data with frequency 3 hour (in other words: 1st observations, the next one is 4th observations, the next is 7th and etc).
Thank you!